# gulp watch task causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

my gulp watch tasks causes an infinite loop in the terminal and it also creates a a lot more .min.js files than expected. I'm pretty new to gulp and any help pointing me in the right direction would help

Here my gulpfile:

```
  /*
  Required
  */

 var gulp = require('gulp'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
   rename = require('gulp-rename');

 /*
 Scripts Task
 */

 gulp.task('scripts', function(){
   gulp.src(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/**/*.min.js]'])
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

/*
Watch Tasks
*/

gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

/*
 Default Task
*/

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're watching for changes in the js directory, and your scripts task also puts the processed code into the js directory, which the watcher picks up and the cycle begins all over again.

You should probably put the processed files in a different directory than the source files, by changing this line: `.pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));`

The alternative is to change your watcher to not watch the files with .min.js at the end, but I can see this getting really messy